# apt-get install "maven" or "maven3"

Tags: apt, maven-3

I need some clarification on how to install the latest version of maven. When I run this command on a new Ubuntu 16.04 server machine (I haven't installed maven yet) I get the following message:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ mvn
The program 'mvn' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install maven
```

But I see other forum posts saying to install "maven3". So my question is what is the difference between apt-get install "maven" and "maven3"? Does "maven" install an older version or does this just point to whatever the latest version is? Should I just use "maven3" instead?

If this helps, I am writing this script to set up a new developer workstation on Ubuntu 16.04, starting from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt-cache show maven | grep Version` for me shows

> ```
> Version: 3.0.5-1
> ```

so the `maven` package is a reasonably recent version of maven 3.x.x.

`apt-cache show maven3` for me yields

> ```
> N: Unable to locate package maven3
> E: No packages found
> ```

so trying to install `maven3` will probably fail unless you have a non-standard set of repos on your search list.

Also see https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=maven